# celerybeat automatically disables periodic task

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, celeryd

I'd like to create a periodic task for celery using *django-celery*'s admin interface. I have a task set up which runs great when called manually or by script. It just doesn't work through *celerybeat*. According to the debug logs the task is set to `enabled = False` on first retrieval and I wonder why.

When adding the periodic task and passing `[1, False]` as positional arguments, the task is automatically disabled and I don't see any further output. When added without arguments the task is executed but raises an exception instantly because I didn't supply the needed arguments (makes sense).

Does anyone see what's the problem here?

Thanks in advance.

This is the output after supplying arguments:

```
[DEBUG/Beat] SELECT "djcelery_periodictask"."id", [...] 
             FROM "djcelery_periodictask" 
             WHERE "djcelery_periodictask"."enabled" = true ; args=(True,)

[DEBUG/Beat] SELECT "djcelery_intervalschedule"."id", [...] 
             FROM "djcelery_intervalschedule" 
             WHERE "djcelery_intervalschedule"."id" = 3 ; args=(3,)

[DEBUG/Beat] SELECT (1) AS "a" 
             FROM "djcelery_periodictask" 
             WHERE "djcelery_periodictask"."id" = 3  LIMIT 1; args=(3,)

[DEBUG/Beat] UPDATE "djcelery_periodictask" 
             SET "name" = E'<taskname>', "task" = E'<task.module.path>', 
                 "interval_id" = 3, "crontab_id" = NULL, 
                 "args" = E'[1, False,]', "kwargs" = E'{}', "queue" = NULL, 
                 "exchange" = NULL, "routing_key" = NULL, 
                 "expires" = NULL, "enabled" = false, 
                 "last_run_at" = E'2011-05-25 00:45:23.242387', "total_run_count" = 9, 
                 "date_changed" = E'2011-05-25 09:28:06.201148' 
             WHERE "djcelery_periodictask"."id" = 3; 
             args=(
                   u'<periodic-task-name>', u'<task.module.path>', 
                   3, u'[1, False,]', u'{}', 
                   False, u'2011-05-25 00:45:23.242387', 9, 
                   u'2011-05-25 09:28:06.201148', 3
             )

[DEBUG/Beat] Current schedule:
<ModelEntry: celery.backend_cleanup celery.backend_cleanup(*[], **{}) {<crontab: 0 4 * (m/h/d)>}
[DEBUG/Beat] Celerybeat: Waking up in 5.00 seconds.
```

**EDIT:** 
It works with the following setting. I still have no idea why it doesn't work with *django-celery*.

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    "example": {
        "task": "<task.module.path>",
        "schedule": crontab(),
        "args": (1, False)
    },
}
```

Comment: Can you post your task and periodictask configuration?

Comment: Thanks for seeing about my issue. I didn't set `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE` because I used django-celery's administration instead. I also checked the [FAQ](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/faq.html#why-won-t-my-task-run) but as I said in the original posting, I'm able to launch the task from the shell manually. Is there something else I could have overlooked?

Comment: Have exactly same problem ... Any solutions?

Comment: Have you tried setting the tasks in `settings.py` with `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE`?

Comment: Yep, it works fine with CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE. But i need it to work with django admin.

Comment: Stupid question, You have set the var CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER in this way ?

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = "djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler"

Answer (score 15):

I had the same issue.  Make sure the arguments are JSON formatted.  For example, try setting the positional args to [1, false] -- lowercase 'false' -- I just tested it on a django-celery instance (version 2.2.4) and it worked.

For the keyword args, use something like {"name": "aldarund"}

Comment: Yes, I'm confirm, the problem is the encoding. In fact for string arguments you have to use double quotes " instead of the single one '.

Answer (score 9):

I got the same problem too.

With the description of PeriodicTask models in djcelery ("JSON encoded positional arguments"), same as Evan answer. I try using python json lib to encode before save.

And this work with me

```
import json 
o = PeriodicTask()
o.kwargs = json.dumps({'myargs': 'hello'})
o.save()
```

celery version 3.0.11

Answer (score 0):

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    "example": {
        "task": "<task.module.path>",
        "schedule": crontab(),
        "enable": False
    },
}
```

I tried and it worked.I run on celery beat v5.1.2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).